# Apply function to convert dataframe rows to vectors

Tags: r, vectorization, lapply, sapply

I have a dataframe with 12665x784 dimension and I need to call a function over each row (this function expects an input of 1x784 from the dataframe and a constant with the same size) and store the result in another vector. The code using for loop is shown bellow:

```
sample <- 1:20
my.constant <- 1:5
dim(sample) <- c(4, 5)
df <- as.data.frame(sample)

my.function <- function (x, y){
  y <- as.matrix(y)
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  return(x%*%y)
}

result <- c()

for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  result<- c(result, my.function(df[row, ], my.constant))
}
```

I've tried the following approach, but it didn't work:

```
result <- sapply(lapply(df, as.vector), my.function, my.constant)
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: you can `?apply`

Comment: @Jaap, I edited the question to provide a reproducible example. Sorry about that.

Comment: `as.matrix(df) %*% my.constant` or `c(as.matrix(df) %*% my.constant)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your function a matrix product?
2. Is your data only numeric values?

Then you just want a matrix product between a matrix and a vector:

```
as.matrix(df) %*% my.constant
```

with possibly using `drop()` if you want a vector instead of a one-column matrix.

Comment: 1. Actually, my function is more complex much more complex than that. I used a dot product to make it simple.
2. All data is only numeric values.

Comment: Okay. Can you use a more complex function? I'll edit my answer with these new information.

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps...

```
id<-c("A", "B", "C")
v1<-c(10, 4, 9)
df<-data.frame(id, v1)


result<-unlist(lapply(df$v1, function(x){
  x+1
}))

result
```

Comment: Why would you mark down my answer? I gave you a reproducible example of how to apply any function you create to all records and then collect them in a vector as you asked. Your functions makes no sense... you need to fix that first. You created one data frame but have two inputs for your function...

Comment: In your case `unlist(lapply(...))` is identical with `sapply(...)`. In the mean time there is a reproducible example in the question.